# Amazon S3 ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE on Laravel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel framework on my subdomain `sub.example.com` trying to implement the connection with Amazon S3 for all the pictures of my website.

This is my Policy for my bucket (`bucket-1`)

```
{
    "Id": "Policy************",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt***********",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-1/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my CORS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I granteed all permissions for my user and only `list` for `Everyone`.

**Why when I upload a picture, that picture is not shown on my website** (`net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`)?

If I navigate to the url of the picture (`https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-1/...`) Chrome shows a warning page with the message `Your connection is not private`

```
s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: *.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Issuer: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
```

The thing that makes me even more baffled is that if I copy paste the same link on another tab, I can see the picture without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, but you should be using `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`... you want a dash instead of a dot after "s3."

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Different regions in S3 have variations in their conventions, depending on age.  What you did would have been valid in eu-central-1, which works both ways, but not in eu-west-1.