# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE while accessing files from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, https, cors, s3-bucket

When I access image from S3 bucket using HTTPS I get error as,  **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE for s3 bucket**.

I want to load image file using HTTPS only.
Below is the link of image file which I can access using HTTP but can not using HTTPS.  https://bucket.leadient.s3.amazonaws.com/9/branding_image/585ce85fa788a.jpg

This is my CORS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I granteed all permissions for my user and only `list` for `Everyone`.

**Why when I upload a picture, that picture is not shown on my website** (`net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`)?
**I have not set any policy for S3 bucket**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer myself.

**The CORS settings were perfect and there is no need to set any policy for bucket**.

The URL is wrong.
**The proper URL is as below**,
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket.leadient/9/branding_image/585ce85fa788a.jpg

First I searched for the region with which bucket is created and respective endpoint for that region.
My buckets region was US west (Oregon) and hence the endpoint became
**s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com**.
And I placed my **bucket.leadient** after the endpoint and error resolved.
**Link helped me**
[Amazon S3 ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE on Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589296/amazon-s3-err-insecure-response-on-laravel#answer-34592550)

Comment: The `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` URL isn't exactly "wrong" -- your content is there, too -- but the dot in your bucket name causes your browser to conclude that the SSL cert isn't trustworthy, because the `*` in a wildcard cert is not permitted to match a dot, and the certificate is for `*.s3.amazonaws.com`.  For bucket names without dots *or* if you aren't using SSL, *both* styles are equivalent.  For IPv6 support, use `https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/...`.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. It is very helpful for me  :)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the information. That really helped me and saved a lot of time.